# How much data is enough to be awarded a PhD?

Tags: phd, thesis

I feel my data is not enough to be awarded a PhD (compared to the work of others in my lab), but I have spent too much of my time as a graduate student (approx 7yrs); should I wind up and defend my thesis (feeling embarrassed all the while), or stay longer?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "enough to satisfy your advisor and department".

Comment: You don't get a PhD just by getting a lot of data.  Otherwise, all the people who conduct surveys would be PhDs.

Answer (score 8):

No particular amount of data can earn you a PhD. One data point, if it's correct and meaningful enough could be enough for the degree. What's important is the new knowledge that whatever data you have allows you to create through your analysis. If you are measuring something very noisy, you may need billions or trillions of data points in order to show the theorized effect. If you are trying to prove that there are indeed black swans in the world, then bringing one specimen back to the Old World is sufficient.

You should ask yourself what new things can you demonstrate with your data, and does your analysis have sufficient statistical power to satisfy others that these conclusions are true. If it does, then you're done, if not, then you may have to collect more data (or find a new hypothesis!).

Comment: Did you want to say that "No amount of data can earn ONE a PhD", or did you actually imply that no amount of data can earn me a PhD. The amount of down-votes to my question is causing this doubt.

Comment: @Navodita: Bill Barth means that there is no quantity X of data such that in all circumstances one can trade in X data for a PhD.

Comment: @Navodita: I didn't downvote the question myself, but I believe the downvotes are a reaction to how the question is posed rather than commentary on you or your work or future prospects.  (You seem to be seeking advice, but it's hard to know what to say without far more information.  Maybe you are being too hard on yourself, and you have done plenty already, or maybe you have accomplished almost nothing.  We have no idea.)

Comment: @Navodita, Pete is right. In addition, no one can tell you that 6 data points or 6 billion data points are required to graduate. You must use the data to make an analysis which constitutes new knowledge about your field. What does your advisor say?